# Is it safe to disable SATA ports in the BIOS to isolate the corresponding hard drives from malware?

Tags: malware, bios, isolation

I have three SATA hard drives that I use every day. Suppose I disable the corresponding SATA ports of these hard drives through my BIOS, add another storage device to my PC, install another instance of Windows 10 and run unsafe executables on it - would my three SATA hard drives be completely isolated and safe?

As I understand it, unmounted partitions are at risk, but not partitions that I exclude by disabling the corresponding SATA ports.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

BIOS is software, malware is software, they potentially have the same capabilities.

I would go with a physical barrier: unplugging the drives or disconnectng their power supply.